Add Object name and Variable Name using Javascript
I Have A Object Called res and i have a variable Called lea
need to concatenate
for example
let lea = "abc";

let res = {
abc:'steve'
};

console.log(res.lea);


So My Output Should Be steve
I tried like this
console.log(res.`${lea}`);


It's just res[lea].

Thank You So Much @Andy I'm Newbie Developer

use this method:
console.log(res[lea]);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly edit your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
